# Is it possible to alter the code inside a proc?

Tags: ruby, proc

to_source provided by the sourcify gem.

I wonder how would one would create these methods?

```
hello = Proc.new{ 2.times{ puts 'hi' } }
hello.to_source #=> 2.times{ puts 'hi' }
hello.call #=> 'hi' 'hi'
hello.change_hi_to_bye!
hello.to_source #=> 2.times{ puts 'bye' }
hello.call #=> 'bye' 'bye'
hello.get_rid_of_block!
hello.to_source #=> 2.times
hello.call #=>
```

I'd be interested in the `get_rid_of_block!` method. Something generic that could strip all the blocks out of all the methods in a proc.

I've had a breif look into `RubyVM::InstructionSequence.of(my_proc).to_a` with a view to altering the build sequence (thought there'd be a nice little `:attach_block` field I could delete, but unfortunately not that I could see.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide these or similar methods by using method_missing(http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing). Just take the method name like string, split it with '_' and make a couple of things you need. It's some kind of Builders' pattern implementation.